# How to pass textbox data to a datagridview in different forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, msdn

I have two forms:

The first form (XML Data Loader) contains a DataGridView with six columns (Name, Width, Height, Length, Dead Weight, Load Capacity)

XML Data Loader also has a button on it, which when pressed opens a new forms window (Add New Car).
Add New Car has six textboxes where train car data is input by a user.

The goal is for the user to be able to click the Save button on Add New Car and the data will be pushed into a new row in the DataGridView on XML Data Loader, but I am having an issue with actually finding a way to do this. Everything else I've found assumes that DataGridViews are being populated through a database, but mine is user-input populated.

---

```
public partial class XMLDataLoader : Form
{
    public XMLDataLoader()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonAddCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewCar addNewCar = new AddNewCar();
        addNewCar.Show();
    }
}
```

### [image]

```
public partial class AddNewCar : Form
{
    public AddNewCar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonNewSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check that all textboxes have some kind of entry
        //ToDo: check the type of data so that only numbers are entered into non-name categories
        if(textBoxNewName.TextLength < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a train name!");
        }
        if (textBoxNewWidth.TextLength < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a train width!");
        }
        if (textBoxNewHeight.TextLength < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a train height!");
        }
        if (textBoxNewLength.TextLength < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a train length!");
        }
        if (textBoxNewDeadWeight.TextLength < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a train dead weight!");
        }
        if (textBoxNewLoadCapacity.TextLength < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a train load capacity!");
        }

        //Save all data input by user to create a new train momentarily
        var newTrainName = textBoxNewName.Text;
        var newTrainWidth = textBoxNewWidth.Text;
        var newTrainHeight = textBoxNewHeight.Text;
        var newTrainLength = textBoxNewLength.Text;
        var newTrainDeadWeight = textBoxNewDeadWeight.Text;
        var newTrainLoadCapacity = textBoxNewLoadCapacity.Text;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: when you click Save you want to create a stored procedure or Query that Inserts that data in to the Cars Table.. then on the Postback of the Parent form you need to call the routine that loads the DataGridview initially and call the dataGridView.DataBind(); also in your Car form if the data is not as expected you need to do a return and set focus to that control..

Comment: `if(textBoxNewName.TextLength < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a train name!");
           textBoxNewName.Focus(); return;
        }` is what you want you could also change to code to do a foreach contrl in Controls and check if cntrl is TextBox and check length set focus to control else continue etc..

Answer (score 2):

First, use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`. That way, you will still be in `buttonAddCar_Click` when the `AddNewCar` dialog closes. The way your code is now, `buttonAddCar_Click` will exit while `AddNewCar` is still visible, and your main window will have lost all contact with the instance of `AddNewCar` that you created.

Secondly, you need to expose the text box values to the caller. So after the dialog closes, `addNewCar.textBoxNewName.Text` will contain the string the user typed into the New Name `TextBox`. But by default that's not public. So add a bunch of properties to expose the values:

```
public String NewName { get { return textBoxNewName.Text; } }
```

In `buttonAddCar_Click` after the call to `ShowDialog()`, you can do whatever you like with the exposed `Text` properties of all those TextBoxes.

I don't do winforms every day now, so it's possible that `textBoxNewName.Text` may throw an exception if you touch it after the form closes. Easy fix! Declare the public properties as regular properties instead of get-only accessors...

```
public String NewName { get; protected set; }
```

...and assign them their values in the OK click event when the user's input passes validation. Which is our next topic.

Lastly, making the user click on (potentially) six popups in succession is enough to make him commit suicide. Instead, I'd recommend declaring a string variable called `message` and concatenating:

```
    string message = "";
    if(textBoxNewName.TextLength < 1)
    {
        message += "Please enter a train name!\n"
    }
    if (textBoxNewWidth.TextLength < 1)
    {
        message += "Please enter a train width!\n";
    }

    //  ...etc....

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
    else
    {
        NewName = textBoxNewName.Text;
        //  ...and so on for the other five properties. 

        //  This will close the form and cause ShowDialog() to
        //  return DialogResult.OK
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

[`Form.DialogResult` is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) a useful adjunct to `Form.ShowDialog()`.

If you have a Cancel button, it doesn't even need a Click method. Just set that [`Button`'s `DialogResult` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) to `DialogResult.Cancel` in the form designer, and it'll assign that value to `Form.DialogResult` when the user clicks it, which will cause the window to close and `ShowDialog` to return `DialogResult.Cancel`.

Another way you could do this is declare a simple class which has all the car-creation data in it: `NewName`, `Width`, etc. Write an overload of `ShowDialog()` which returns that type, or which takes a reference to that type and returns `bool` (true for OK). If user cancels it returns null or false; if user clicks OK and passes validation, it returns an instance of that class, or in the reference version, populates the members of the reference that was passed in, and then returns true.

If you already have a class which represents a Car (from Entity Framework or whatever), you would just use that.

But the way I've described above is consistent with usage in built-in WinForms dialogs like `FileOpen` and so on. My touchstone when working in any environment like WinForms, MFC, WPF, etc. is **What Would the Framework Do?** That's almost invariably the right answer, because a) successful frameworks tend to be reasonably well designed (they are used successfully by people who can't access their internals or consult their implementors), and b) anybody who interacts your code will know exactly what to expect because he already knows the framework's way of doing things.

Every time I use third party code that thinks it's smarter than the framework, I can't help noticing how much dumber it is.

Comment: "enough to make him commit suicide" ah man - I had a hearty laugh at that. Ok, I'll give this a shot, it seems sensible so I think it will work. Be back soon! I am curious though, based on the way you say that data will stay in variables for the textboxes after they hit save, what's to keep it from staying there when they hit Cancel?

Comment: @AlexWatts Good point -- it *will* stay there when they hit Cancel, too. I would make your OK/Cancel buttons set [Form.DialogResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx), which closes the Form and causes `ShowDialog()` to return the value you assigned to `Form.DialogResult`: `DialogResult.OK`, etc. I'll update.

Comment: So I tried saving the textbox data in the main form's button click buttonAddCar_Click, but it says the text values are protected & cannot be accessed. The DialogResult was a good addition though!

My very original thought was that I would need to package my data in a return statement or class of some kind to send it back to the main form (XML Data Loader), but it's been so long since I've done a simple forms setup I'm a bit rusty

Comment: @AlanWatts Ah, OK. In that case you may be able to make the textboxes public in the designer, OR you can define public properties which expose their text values: `public String NewName { get { return textBoxNewName.Text; } }`, etc. That's probably best.

Comment: Ah ok, that sounds kind of like what I was thinking. Let me give that making public getters thing a try real quick

Answer (score 0):

Hat tip to @Ed Plunkett for the help - it's working swimmingly now!!

---

```
public partial class XMLDataLoader : Form
{
    public XMLDataLoader()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Function for the Add Car button to open the Add New Car window
    private void buttonAddCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewCar displayNewCarWindow = new AddNewCar();
        displayNewCarWindow.ShowDialog();

        dataGridViewMainCarDisplay.Rows.Add(displayNewCarWindow.NewTrainName
                                           , displayNewCarWindow.NewTrainWidth
                                           , displayNewCarWindow.NewTrainHeight
                                           , displayNewCarWindow.NewTrainLength
                                           , displayNewCarWindow.NewTrainDeadWeight
                                           , displayNewCarWindow.NewTrainLoadCapacity);
    }

    //Function for the Remove Car button to delete the currently
        //selected car from the datagridview
    private void buttonRemoveCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

---

```
public partial class AddNewCar : Form
{
    public AddNewCar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Get and Private Set methods to pass textbox data to XMLDataLoader form
    public String NewTrainName { get; private set; }
    public String NewTrainWidth { get; private set; }
    public String NewTrainHeight { get; private set; }
    public String NewTrainLength { get; private set; }
    public String NewTrainDeadWeight { get; private set; }
    public String NewTrainLoadCapacity { get; private set; }

    private void buttonNewSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check that all textboxes have some kind of entry
        //ToDo: check the type of data so that only numbers are entered into non-name categories
        var message = String.Empty;

        if(textBoxNewName.TextLength < 1)
        {
            message += "Please enter a train name!\n";
        }
        if (textBoxNewWidth.TextLength < 1)
        {
            message += "Please enter a train width!\n";
        }
        if (textBoxNewHeight.TextLength < 1)
        {
            message += "Please enter a train height!\n";
        }
        if (textBoxNewLoadCapacity.TextLength < 1)
        {
            message += "Please enter a train length!\n";
        }
        if (textBoxNewDeadWeight.TextLength < 1)
        {
            message += "Please enter a train dead weight!\n";
        }
        if (textBoxNewLength.TextLength < 1)
        {
            message += "Please enter a train load capacity!\n";
        }

        //Save all data input by user to create a new train
        NewTrainName = textBoxNewName.Text;
        NewTrainWidth = textBoxNewWidth.Text;
        NewTrainHeight = textBoxNewHeight.Text;
        NewTrainLength = textBoxNewLoadCapacity.Text;
        NewTrainDeadWeight = textBoxNewDeadWeight.Text;
        NewTrainLoadCapacity = textBoxNewLength.Text;

        //Handle the form execution for whether or not a textbox is empty
        if (message != String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
    }        

    //Function for the Cancel button to close the Add New Car window
    private void buttonNewCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Now to make the "Remove" button functional and whatnot, but the peak of the mountain has been crossed ^_^

Thnx again @Ed Plunkett

Comment: Glad it's working! This really belongs in question, not in a separate answer.

Comment: Yeah I really don't have a strong handle on how StackOverFlow always wants answers and stuff structured, so I thought since it was the solution version it would be considered an answer :P

Comment: If an answer resolves the issue, you can accept it by clicking the checkbox icon. This helps future readers know which answer did the trick.