# Get the value of the textbox and put it into a datagridview different form c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I have five textbox and a button in Form1 and than I want to send values textbox to datagridview in Form2. when trying to run it will display the error message "does not contain a constructor that takes 5 arguments "
this code for Form1 :

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string IdStudent = textBox1.Text;
        string NameStudent = textBox2.Text;
        string AddressStudent = textBox3.Text;
        string EmailStudent = textBox4.Text;
        string PhoneNumStudent = textBox5.Text;
        Form2 frm = new Form2(IdStudent,NameStudent,AddressStudent,EmailStudent,PhoneNumStudent);
        this.Close();
```

And this code form2 :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(String User, string IdStudent, string NameStudent, string AddressStudent, string EmailStudent, string PhoneNumStudent)

    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int row = 0;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2;
        dataGridView1["IdStudent", row].Value = IdStudent;
        dataGridView1["NameStudent", row].Value = NameStudent;
        dataGridView1["AddressStudent", row].Value = AddressStudent;
        dataGridView1["Email", row].Value = EmailStudent;
        dataGridView1["Phone", row].Value = PhoneNumStudent;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

there anything you can provide feedback or solution?

Comment: it seems that you are sending 5 values and Form2 expects to receive 6 values.You are not receiving this (String User)

Comment: I use a (String User) to display the username of the login process before.

Comment: Not sure i get  what you meant but if you are sending 5,you have to receive 5 .Please try without this String user and if you want this string user,then need to add one more input parameter in Form2

Comment: overall I have 3 form. FormLogin , Form1 , Form2 . FormLogin I use to login. after a successful login , the username will be displayed on Form1 . and String User I use to display the username . it has been successful but that puzzles me is how to show value to the textbox on form1 to datagridview on form2

Comment: Dude,you have to pass it again to form2 or post your entire code and will give you corrected one.

Answer (score 1):

i can't send comment,

remove "String User" from Form2 cunstroctor parameters or send it from form1

Comment: overall I have 3 form. FormLogin , Form1 , Form2 . FormLogin I use to login. after a successful login , the username will be displayed on Form1 . and String User I use to display the username . it has been successful but that puzzles me is how to show value to the textbox on form1 to datagridview on form2

Comment: now you has error message "does not contain a constructor that takes 5 arguments " and this is because of defining 6 argument in Form2.if you want save your logined username across the application,don't need to send that to every form,just save it in a Static Variable and get that in other forms by calling static var

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your feedback and give solution. but I have found the solution of my problems at the following links :
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360841/how-to-pass-textbox-data-to-a-datagridview-in-different-forms?rq=1)